# Export DataTable to Excel unable to open file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

I am trying to export DataTable into excel file (.xlsx).

In jQuery, I am removing the unwanted rows.

When I try to open the excel file, it is showing:
    "Excel found unreadable content in '[filename].xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

The error is showing as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <recoveryLog 
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"> 
    <logFileName>error128600_02.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected 
    in file '[filename].xlsx'</summary><removedRecords summary="Following is a 
    list of removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: Cell information 
    from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord></removedRecords> 
    </recoveryLog>

The exported file is opening fine in OpenOffice with removed rows.
```

Here is the code to remove unwanted rows:
I have 5 Columns in my DataTable and removing the unwanted rows based on columns 3,4,5

```
customize: function (xlsx) {
                              var exportData=[];
                              var sheet =xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                              var clR = $('row', sheet);
                              var clR = $('row', sheet);



                                 $('row', sheet).filter(function () {
                                        var attr = $(this).attr('r');

                                         if(attr>3)
                                          {
                                              if($(this).context.children.length===5){

                                                          var Item1= parseInt($(this).context.children[2].children[0].textContent);
                                                          var Item2= parseInt($(this).context.children[3].children[0].textContent);  
                                                          var Item3= parseInt($(this).context.children[4].children[0].textContent);  

                                                        if(Item1===0 && Item2 ===0 && Item3===0 ){

                                                           return true;
                                                         } 
                                                         else{
                                                           exportData.push([{ key: 'A', value: $(this).context.children[0].children[0].textContent },
                                                                           { key: 'B', value: $(this).context.children[1].children[0].textContent },
                                                                           { key: 'C', value: $(this).context.children[2].children[0].textContent },
                                                                           { key: 'D', value: $(this).context.children[3].children[0].textContent },
                                                                           { key: 'E', value: $(this).context.children[4].children[0].textContent }]);
                                                         }
                                                        return false;
                                             }
                                         }
                                 }).remove();



                              //update Row
                              clR.each(function () {`enter code here`
                                  var attr = $(this).attr('r');
                                  var ind = parseInt(attr);

                                  if(ind>3){
                                  $(this).remove();
                                  }
                              });

                              // Create row before data
                              $('row c ', sheet).each(function () {
                                  var attr = $(this).attr('r');
                                  var pre = attr.substring(0, 1);
                                  if(pre>3){
                                     $(this).remove();
                                  }
                              });



                              function Addrow(index,data) {
                                  msg='<row r="'+index+'">'
                                  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                                      var key=data[i].key;
                                      var value=data[i].value;
                                      msg += '<c t="inlineStr" r="' + key + index + '">';
                                      msg += '<is>';
                                      msg +=  '<t>'+value+'</t>';
                                      msg+=  '</is>';
                                      msg+='</c>';
                                  }
                                  msg += '</row>';
                                  return msg;
                              }
                              //insert
                               var addrows="";

                                exportData.each(function (item,index) {
                                    var r1 = Addrow(index+4, item);
                                    addrows=r1+addrows;
                                });

                               sheet.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = sheet.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML+addrows;                                         
                      }
```

Comment: Are you saving excel format 2003 (xlx) or excel format 2007 (xlsx)?  The Jet driver cannot save format 2007.

Comment: saving in excel format 2007 (xlsx)

Comment: Then why : '[filename].xls'?

Comment: Sorry- its '[filename].xlsx'.

Comment: The important question is: How do you remove these rows?

Comment: I've seen this error when the wrong extension is put on an excel file like putting on a 2003 excel xlsx, or on a 2007 excel xls.  You may try to rename the extension and see what happens.  Xml files should have xml as the extension.

Comment: The excel file was opening fine before I tried removing the unwanted rows.